# How can I use RxJava in a flutter plugin on the android side?

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, rx-java, flutter-plugin

I added the following statements to my code to my module level build.gradle file so I can use Rx in my flutter plugin.

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.x.y"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:2.2.7'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

The IDE does not seem to recognize the libraries(io.reactivex) when I type to declare

`val observable : Observable`

Does this mean I cannot use RxJava in a flutter plugin? If I cannot use it, why? And what other libraries would fall under this category?

Answer (score 0):

in flutter if you want to add a dependency to your project, you must add it to your **pubspec.yaml** file which is located in root of your project. main maven for dart/flutter packages is [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)
the pubspec.yaml is like below

```
name: YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
description: A new Flutter project.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  // here is list of your dependencies
  get: ^4.1.4
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  ...

  // IMPORTANT : be careful with indents
  // more about pubspec.yaml file -> https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec
```

if you are looking for a solution to use observers and observable variables, you would better use **State Management** libraries. *(but if you are looking for multi-threading, that's a different story ... )*

in flutter programming there is **RxDart** library, that is like RxJava for reactive programming. you can read more about RxDart at its document -> [link](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart)
I highly recommend you use **GetX** to manage your states, which is so easy to use and powerful.
plz check out GetX in pub.dev -> [direct link](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

hope may help :)